# SSH to EC2 using Bitvise Tunnelier on Windows

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2

Sorry for the basic question. I created a small EC2 instance and had a hard time of connecting to it. Below are my steps:

1. Download the .pem key from AWS console and change it to read-only.
2. Import the read-only key into Bitvise Tunnelier Keypair Mannager as slot 1.
3. Fill in the `username` as `ubuntu` (Ubuntu Server 12.04.3 LTS), `Host` as `ec2-54-235-51-245.compute-1.amazonaws.com`, `Port` as 22.
4. Click the Login button and got timeout error
5. I tried to Ping the public IP, but got timeout, while from the console, it said my instance was running well.

I am using the default security rule:

```
Ports   Protocol  Source    default
-1      icmp    sg-c71bacaf    ✔
0-65535 tcp     sg-c71bacaf    ✔
0-65535 udp     sg-c71bacaf    ✔
```

I really appreciate any suggestions on talking to EC2 in windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you allow port 22 inbound in your EC2 security group.

To add a rule for SSH:

- Next to "Create a new rule" choose "SSH"
- Click "Add Rule"
- Click "Apply Rule Changes"

Comment: Thanks. I am using the default sceurity rule. And it looks like Ports     `Protocol Source default
-1 icmp sg-c71bacaf ✔
0-65535 tcp sg-c71bacaf ✔
0-65535 udp sg-c71bacaf ✔`

Comment: You need to add a rule for SSH. Edited my answer with instructions.

Comment: I have added a rule like this `22 (SSH) 0.0.0.0/0` and will test it after reboot.